# Инициализация CoreData

Tags: objective-c, ios, coredata, uitableview

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку в Core Data. Мне нужно при запуске приложения создать объекты для 2  Entity: Provider и Country.

```
-(NSArray *) getObjects
{
    self.fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [self.fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    //[self.fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [self.fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.resultArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.resultArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (![self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest error:nil]) {
        [self initData];
    }
    return self.resultArray;
}
-(NSArray *) getProviders
{
    self.providerFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [self.providerFetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    //[self.fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [self.providerFetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.providersResultArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.providersResultArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.providerFetchRequest error:&error];

    if (![self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:self.providerFetchRequest error:nil]) {
        [self initData];
    }
    return self.providersResultArray;
}
-(void) initData
{
    Country *france = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    france.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"France"];

    Provider *orangeFR = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    orangeFR.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Orange"];
    orangeFR.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Champ De Mars"];
    orangeFR.country = france;
    Provider *sfrFR = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    sfrFR.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SFR"];
    sfrFR.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SFR Adress"];
    sfrFR.country = france;

    Provider *BeelineRU = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    BeelineRU.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Beeline"];
    BeelineRU.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Beeline adress"];
    Provider *MTSRU = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    MTSRU.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MTS"];
    MTSRU.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MTS Adress"];
    //NSArray *RUProviders = @[BeelineRU, MTSRU];

    //[france addProvider:[NSSet setWithArray:FRProviders]];

    Country *russia = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    russia.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Russia"];
    //[russia addProvider:[NSSet setWithArray:RUProviders]];
    [russia addProviderObject:BeelineRU]; ***// так правильней или как с orangeFR.country = france;??***
    [russia addProviderObject:MTSRU];

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    [self getObjects];

}
```

Как мне потом при повторном запуске приложения получить эти объекты вновь не создавая их?
Как мне подсчитать количество Country объектов и как правильно передать Provider в следующий контроллер в методе  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:? Как в следующем контролере подсчитать уже кол-во Provider?

> -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*
> )indexPath {
>
> ```
> [self getProviders];
> NSArray *countries = self.resultArray;
> Country *selectedCountry = countries[indexPath.row];
> Provider *selectedProvider = selectedCountry.provider;
> ```
>
> //[selectedCountry
> valueForKey:@"provider"];
>     //NSArray *selectedProvider = [selectedCountry
> valueForKey:@"provider"];
>
> ```
> MSTProviderViewController *providerViewController = [[MSTProviderViewController
> ```
>
> alloc]init];
>     [self.navigationController pushViewController:providerViewController
> animated:YES];
>     providerViewController.providers = selectedProvider;
>
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как мне потом при повторном запуске приложения получить эти объекты вновь не создавая их?**

**создаем NSFetchRequest:**

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
```

**задаем ему NSEntityDescription того, что хотим искать:**

```
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

**настраиваем (если нужно) дополнительные параметры поиска:**

```
request.sortDescriptors = @[/*сюда можно запихать массив объектов NSSortDescriptor, если результаты нужно сортировать*/];
            /* можно добавить предикат чтобы выбирать данные только во определенному условию, например:
            request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"someKey == %@", someObject];
            */
```

**настоятельно рекомендую всегда использовать** `request.fetchBatchSize = 20`, это здорово оптимизирует память и производительность

ну и, собственно, **выполняем**:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetched = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; // в fetched упадут результаты в виде массива объектов Country
```

**Как мне подсчитать количество Country объектов**

используя созданный ранее NSFetchRequest

```
NSInteger numberOfCountries = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

**как правильно передать Provider в следующий контроллер в методе didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?**

у вас все верно написано, только вы сначала отдайте данные в новый `UIViewControler,` а потом уже делайте `pushViewController:animated:`, пушим всегда в самом низу метода

Comment: @iFreeman спасибо за развернутый ответ! А как подсчитать Provider во втором контролере? и как при старте приложения проверять нужно ли создать объекты заново, (!fetched) будет достаточно?

Comment: да можно например создать NSFetchRequest, если конечно у тебя Provider относится в Country как один к одному, если связь to-many, то можешь передавать Country.providers.count. Проверить, есть ли объекты ты можешь также выполнив NSFetchRequest на каунт, если что-то есть - не создавай. Если в приложении нужна более сложная логика и нужно убедиться, что только при первом старте идет заполнение базы - можно сохранить Bool флаг в NSUserDefaults, что-то типа [[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] setObject:@YES forKey: @"com.myApp.initial_data_preloaded"], а потому его проверять при старте

Comment: к сожалению у меня не очень получилось с Provider, при попытке обратиться `NSArray *countries = self.resultArray;
    Country *selectedCountry = countries[indexPath.row];
    Provider *selectedProvider = selectedCountry.provider;` выдает relationship fault. код подкорректировал